# How to convert text to list in python

Tags: python, list, file, text, logic

```py
input="""
intro: hey,how are you
i am fine

intro:
hey, how are you
Hope you are fine
"""

output= [['hey,how are you i am fine'],['hey, how are you Hope you are fine']]

for text in f:
    text = text.strip()
```

Comment: Please clearify your question.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into something like regex or just use

`input.split("intro:")` or `input.splitlines()` to generate a list of strings. That would not result in the form you have below. But since your question is not clear thats the best i can do.

Comment: As we can see text is in separate lines so, we want text of separate lines in single list for every intro

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by splitting the input data by the string `intro:`. This will give you a list of the required items. You can clean this up a little more by removing the `\n` and leading/trailing spaces.

As an example:

```py
data = """
intro: hey,how are you
i am fine

intro:
hey, how are you
Hope you are fine
"""
only_intro = []
for intro in data.split("intro:"):
    if not intro.isspace():
        only_intro.append(intro.replace('\n', ' ').lstrip().rstrip())
print(only_intro)
```

which gives the following output:

```
['hey,how are you i am fine', 'hey, how are you Hope you are fine']
```

Answer (score -1):

We can use `re.findall` here in multiline mode:

```py
inp = """intro: hey,how are you i am fine

intro: hey, how are you Hope you are fine"""

lines = re.findall(r'^\w+:\s*(.*)$', inp, flags=re.M)
print(lines)
```

This prints:

```
['hey,how are you i am fine', 'hey, how are you Hope you are fine']
```

Comment: text is in separate lines and we want text in lists of list for every intro respectively =
"""
intro: hey,how are you
i am fine

intro:
hey, how are you
Hope you are fine
"""